# upstart config to start sync daemon as non-root user

Tags: upstart

I am planning to use [inosync](http://bb.xnull.de/projects/inosync/)  to sync data from master server to several client servers. I have created a user called rsyncuser in both master and slaves with access permissions and passwordless ssh access from master to slave servers.

Inosync is working when I use it from the command line as rsyncuser.

Next I want this to start automatically when server is turned on. I figured upstart is the way to get this working.

I am unable to find the right upstart command to get this working.

Here is my upstart conf file. The problem seems to be around running "inosync -d -c /etc/inosync/inosync_rsyncuser.py" as a given user.

As you can see I have tried a number of various options!

```
description     "start inosync to sync data to other CDN Servers as rsyncuser"
console output
#start on startup
#stop on shutdown
start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems)
stop on runlevel [016]

#start on runlevel [2345]
#stop on runlevel [!2345]
#kill timeout 30
env RUN_AS_USER=rsyncuser

expect fork

script
   echo "Inosync updtart job seems to have started" >> /tmp/upstart.log
#   exec sudo -u rsyncuser -c "ls -la" >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
#   LOGFILE=/var/log/logfile.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.log

#   exec su - $RUN_AS_USER -c "inosync -d -c /etc/inosync/inosync_rsyncuser.py" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
#  exec  su -c "ls -la" >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
#   emit inosync_running
end script
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo by default stomps on most of the environment. Try this (adding -E):

```
exec sudo -E -u rsyncuser -c "ls -la" >> /tmp/upstart.log 2>&1
```

`-E` tells sudo to preserve the environment.